# Time you spend on Physics SE

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

I'm not sure if this is on topic on meta but we don't have a meta-meta to ask whether it is appropriate to ask this on meta. Anyway my question is the following:

How much time do you spend on average on Physics SE per day?

Comment: Does having it open in the background while working count as spending time on it?

Comment: I'd say it counts since you are probably regularly checking if there is a question that you can answer or reviewing first post queues or whatever.

Comment: ..... Yes.... regularly

Comment: @JimtheEnchanter also including the time in chat!

Comment: Including weekends?

Comment: Why not include them too? You are heading for 10-15 hours aren't you?

Comment: Per day? Nowhere close. If we include weekends and whatnot, I'm in the range of 2-4 hours, on average.

Comment: @JimtheEnchanter That was an obvious exaggeration :)

Comment: I'm not sure I even want to know how much time I'm on here...

Comment: I log in when I get to work in the morning and sign out when I leave. So, if you want, you could say all of that is time I'm on this site. But if you were my supervisor, I wouldn't tell you that

Comment: This is just Physics, not SE as a whole, right?

Comment: @HDE226868 yes just Physics SE

Answer (score 22):

It's very variable. I check the questions in the morning, at lunchtime and in the evening, but how long I spend on the site depends on whether any of the questions catch my eye.

It can take a surprisingly long time to write a thorough answer, especially since the answers that are most fun are the ones at the edge of my knowledge, so I have to spend time researching them. It's not unusual for me to spend an hour on an involved answer. Some of the canonical Q/As I've written have taken a day or more, but that's a special case as it's more akin to writing an article.

I suspect the reason we so often see experienced site members posting brief answers as comments is because it can take such an investment in time to write a proper answer. I trust the OPs appreciate just how much effort is put in on their behalf :-)

Comment: John and Kyle (and many others), I'm sure I speak for a lot of people when I say thanks for your efforts! - you are Stakhanovs of Stack Exchange!

Comment: [For reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexey_Stakhanov) to innisfree's comment

Comment: Hi sir, how much time did you take to write the Brazil-nut effect answer? It was a great answer indeed. Also'll not forget to mention the brilliant (to me) explanation of slow-amplitude modulation with the illustration; indeed have taken much time! BTW, you can take this comment synonymous to **a big thank you** for spending much time to explain the concepts, without getting annoyed by later queries :)

Comment: @Pacerier: typically one of my canonical Q/As would take intermittent bursts of activity spread over a few days. The total time take is very variable, but around 8 hours is probably reasonably typical. Bear in mind that much of this time is reading around the area, so it isn't 8 hours tapping away at the keyboard.

Answer (score 5):

Just take a look at the stats page of each of the [review pages](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review) (or my 4 [Steward badges](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/107/steward?userid=25301)) and my [Marshal badge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/82/marshal?userid=25301) and you can see *how* I spend most of my time on Physics.SE (which is also a subtle hint for those with 2k+ rep to start reviewing what you can & those with 3k+ rep to start reviewing the close queue).

I usually spend about 20-30 minutes in the morning (while cooking breakfast & drinking coffee) on the [(Android) mobile app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin&hl=en) looking at questions that were posted (trying to manually review, since there isn't a review page on the app) and voting up/down as I see fit. I typically spend another hour or so in the afternoon (during the kids' nap time) and at night (after the kids' bed time) reviewing and answering/commenting what I can. All tolled, that's between **2 and 3 hours per day** and less on weekends that I actually spend time doing things on the site.<sup>1</sup>

Like John, if I find a question that interests me I'll think about the answer for a bit (usually while reviewing and doing daily duties) and spend at least 20 minutes writing one up (usually longer if I need to find links or if the wife and/or kids need attention)--this number is subtracted from the time spent on reviews, so the net 2-3 hours is the same.

<sup>1 The numbers quoted here are for my *active* time on Physics; the tab is open in the background in my browser always, so once the computer is un-suspended (re-animated?) I'm technically "on." In this case, the number is probably closer to 6 hours a day (and longer when I was still a student working 10 hours days).</sup>

Comment: "... _longer when I was still a student working 10 hours days_". Somebody ping his supervisor :P

Comment: He knows I spent time doing stuff on this site, I promoted it all the time.

Comment: @KyleKanos, Any bonus points as a result?